# How to make brew install a package only if it is not yet installed, and upgrade otherwise?

Tags: homebrew

I found it surprisingly hard to make `brew` either install a package (if it is missing) or upgrade it (if it is already installed). Is there no simple command / arguments to do that?

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20802425/1127485), I ended up doing (at the example of the `git` package)

```
brew ls --versions git && brew upgrade git || brew install git
```

after doing a `brew update`, obviously. However, that still seems clumsy to me compared to other package managers.

Comment: Seems like a pretty decent solution to me. I don’t think there’s an _easier_ or _more compact_ way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homebrew doesn't support that way of use.

To reduce keypresses you could leverage SHELL-scripting (makes sense to add to your SHELL's .rc-file), say:

```
brewIn() { if brew ls --versions "$1"; then brew upgrade "$1"; else brew install "$1"; fi }
```

— Works both in Bash and Zsh. Usage: `brewIn …formulae…`. But none except this.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that there's indeed no better way, unfortunately.